# Return a list of items from a text file to be indexed

Tags: python, list, indexing

I am trying to write a function that returns a list of cities from a text file so that when the function is called, you can put an index after it, and it will return the corresponding city.

Example:

```
citylist('MYFILE.txt')[3]
```

So far, I have

```
def citylist(filename):
    assert type(filename)==str

    with open(filename) as FileObject:
        for line in FileObject:
            q=line.split('\t')
            print q[12],
```

There are 500 complaints. After I split each string (complaint) into a list, the city name is the 13th index in the list. But I am stuck as all I can get it to do is print all of the city names as non data types that cannot be indexed.

Comment: Can you clarify on this "but I am stuck as all I can get it to do is print all of the city names as non data types that cannot be indexed" ?

Comment: Functions need to return something in order for you to do something with their result.

Comment: asserting that you get a certain type isn't very typical in python code.  the more common usage is to try to use whatever you have and handle any exceptions that might occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a list and return it:

```
def citylist(filename):
  assert type(filename)==str  #isinstance(filename,str) is more idiomatic here.

  output = []
  with open(filename) as FileObject:
    for line in FileObject:
      q = line.split('\t')
      output.append(q[12]) 
  return output
```

Alternatively, and more succinctly:

```
def citylist(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        return [ line.split('\t')[12] for line in f ]
```

where I've built the list using a [list-comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) in this last example.

Comment: thanks .. both work.. forgot to add I need to get rid of trailing whitespace so just added strip method to q[12]..kinda disappointed I could get this one Im a newb still but thanks

Comment: @MarcoJ -- No problem.  Don't worry about it -- Just keep working at it and you'll get used to the way things are done in python.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
def citylist(filename):
  assert isinstance(filename, str)
  return [line.split('\t')[12] for line in open(filename)]
```

The list comprehension is equivalent to the following expanded `for` loop:

```
result = []
for line in open(filename):
  result.append(line.split('\t')[12])
```